# Какой формат изображений использовать при динамической смене изображений

Tags: android, png

Цель: в верхней части экрана в виде прямоугольника вставлять изображения, учитывая, что изображения меняются динамически.   Для вопросов в программе создан фрагмент, в котором в зависимости от вопроса, подставляются изображения. Поместить в `drawable` не могу, т.к. вопросов много и писать кучу условий, чтобы для каждого вопроса подбирался нужный ресурс из `drawable` не вариант. Проще поместить всё в `assets` и назвать изображения так, чтобы легко составить правильный путь к изображению.  Я решил использовать `nine-patch`, но изображения в `jpg`, которые занимали 25 кб, стали весить 180 кб.  Можно, конечно, сжать до `png-8` , но тут тоже есть какие то свои подводные камни, т.к. я находил информацию о том, что андроид студия самостоятельно конвертирует из `png-8` в `png-24`  при упаковке в apk. вот об [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632489/android-aapt-tool-why-convert-my-png8-to-png24). 
   Что посоветуете? Изображения не имеют таких требований как в приложениях "Найди 10 отличий" . Не увеличиваемое изображение к вопросу.

Comment: не совсем понятна суть вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишите: *"Проще поместить всё в assets и назвать изображения так, чтобы легко составить правильный путь к изображению."*

Это можно сделать и с `Drawble`:

```
String name = \\ваша реализация составления имени файла
int img = getResources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", MyActivity.this.getPackageName());
```